# How to combine 2 way databinding with model driven forms?

Tags: angular, angular2-forms

In angular 2 one possibility of building forms is the model driven way. As far as I understand, the controls loose their 2 way databinding, in opposite to the template driven way with ngModel.

What is the best way of combining 2 way data binding with model driven forms?
I tryed to use model binding with [value] :

```
<form [ngFormModel]="hero" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="name">Name</label>
    <input type="text" id="name" [value]="hero.value.name" 
           class="form-control" ngControl="name">
```

That seems to work: If the model is changed programmatically, the control is also updated.

But I'm not sure if this is the correct way. I noticed, if I try to update the validations by

```
this.hero.updateValueAndValidity();
```

in a timeout function, the controls value and the model are resetted to the original value.

I'm using angular 2 beta.15.

Comment: can you elaborate a little more ? it's not clear enough what are you trying to do

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In fact you can mix `ngControl` and `ngModel` like this:

```
<form ngForm="hero" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="name">Name</label>
    <input type="text" id="name" [(ngModel)]="hero.value.name" 
       class="form-control" ngControl="name">
  </div>
</form>
```

In this case, you have two-way binding on the `hero.value.name`. `ngModel` allows to attach properties on input fields and make them synchronized (two-way binding). Controls allow to apply validation, get informed if fields are valid, touched, ... and to be notified of updates (`valueChanges`).

See this plunkr: https://plnkr.co/edit/XnfGDE7vTTogH8yxtxjo?p=preview.

That said you can mix inline (`ngControl`) and programmatic form definition (`ngFormModel`).

See this article for more details:

- http://restlet.com/blog/2016/02/11/implementing-angular2-forms-beyond-basics-part-1/

Comment: OK, thank you, I think I got it. I want to use the imperative way to create the validations, but I didn't realize the difference between ngControl and ngFormControl. You answer helped me.