# angular 2 cannot read property of undefined

Tags: angular

I am getting the below error

Cannot read property 'value' of undefined

Below is my code

### Template

```
<select class="form-control form-control-lg" formControlName="contractor" (ngModelChange)="onChange($event.target.value)" >
                    <option *ngFor="let contrac of contractors" [ngValue]="contrac">{{contrac.name}}</option>
                </select>

 <label class="control-label col-lg-2">Agency</label>
            <div class="col-lg-10">
                <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-lg" placeholder="Payroll Number" formControlName ="selectedAgency">
            </div>
```

### Component

```
 ngOnInit() {
        this.form = this.fb.group({
            agency: ['', Validators.required],
            contractor: ['', Validators.required],
            selectedAgency : ['', Validators.required]

        });

 onChange = (contrac) => {
        alert(contrac.vendor);
        this.form.patchValue({ selectedAgency: contrac.vendor });
    }
```

Is there anything that missed out here?

-Alan-

Comment: try like this,  `(change)="onChange($event.target.value)"`

Comment: Maybe in ngOnlnit it is contractor and in ngFor it is contractors, not sure if this is correct

Comment: this.form.patchValue is not defined

Comment: also, I think `[ngModel]` is missing

Comment: @Sravan, changing it to (change)="..." get rid of the error. However, the value of "vendor" is returned as "undefined"

Comment: try alerting `alert(vendor);`

Comment: I am geting 10:Object

Comment: whats the selected value?

Comment: try `alert(JSON.parse(vendor));` and you will get to know what is present in object

Answer (score 0):

It should be :

```
(ngModelChange)="onChange($event)"
```

... or yet using `(change)`:

```
(change)="onChange($event.target.value)"
```

But, seems like you're only using this to set a value for another control in form, right?

So, you can use `[ngModel]` on the input that you want to set the value, as below:

```
<select class="form-control form-control-lg" formControlName="contractor">
  <option *ngFor="let contrac of contractors" 
          [ngValue]="contrac">{{contrac.name}}</option>
</select>

<label class="control-label col-lg-2">Agency</label>
<div class="col-lg-10">      
  <input type="text" 
         class="form-control form-control-lg" 
         placeholder="Payroll Number" 
         formControlName ="selectedAgency" 
         [ngModel]="myForm.get('contractor').value.vendor">
</div>
```

Comment: How do I use that value in my component so that I can pass it another service at later stage?

Comment: I mentioned in the begin, how you can watch the changes. Have you tested it?

Comment: @PankajParkar, well, until today I've never found nothing saying that's bad or good. Anyway it's an optional approach, I suggested two before :)

Comment: `formControlName` is pretty much the equivalent of an ngModel and name attribute combination in template-driven forms.

Comment: I agree, BUT in this specific case I think it's normal. Also I didn't even suggest to use with `2 way data-binding` (banana syntax), it's just `one way data binding`. [**This answer**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36843938/how-to-combine-2-way-databinding-with-model-driven-forms#answer-36849884) says it's perfectly normal. Also, as I said, the OP can use any approach that I suggested.

Comment: @PankajParkar: please, if you find something about this, let me know.