# Multiple Search Angular8 Error 'Cannot read property 'value' of undefined'

Tags: angular, typescript, api, angular8

I created **`form`** with two search criteria `"breedName"` which is text input and `"speciesId"` which is combo box selectable but I got this error while searching: `Cannot read property 'value' of undefined`.

The problem come from **speciesId** which is giving me undefined if I tried to change.

> How can I fix the undefined error and get the speciesId value while
> changing the speciesId combo box data?

Here is what I did:

**breeds.component.html**

```
<form class="form-inline">
<input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="search" placeholder="Enter Breed Name ..."
    formControlName="breedName" name="breedName" id="breedName" aria-label="Search" (input)="getBreedsSearch($event,0)">
<select class="select-option form-control" #speciesId name="speciesId"
(change)="getBreedsSearch('',$event)">
    <option [ngValue]=0 hidden selected>-- select species name --</option>
    <option value=0>-- Select All --</option>
    <option *ngFor="let data of speciesList" [ngValue]="data.speciesId">
        {{data.speciesName}}
    </option>
</select>
```

**breeds.service.ts**

```
getBreedsSearch(breedName: string, speciesId: number) {

    if(speciesId === undefined || speciesId === null)
    {
        speciesId = 0;
        console.log("Species Id = " + speciesId);
    }

    let params = new HttpParams()
        .set("breedName", breedName)
        .set("speciesId", speciesId.toString());

    console.log(params);
    return this.http.get<Apiresponse>(this.baseUrl + 'BreedsMaster/GetBreedsSearch', { params: params })
}
```

**breeds.component.ts**

```
speciesId: number;
breedName: string = "";

getBreedsSearch(breedName, speciesId) {
    this.breedName = breedName.target.value;
    console.log("breedName value = " + this.breedName);
    this.speciesId = speciesId;
    console.log("speciesId value = " + this.speciesId);
    if (this.breedName != null && this.breedName != "") {
        console.log("Inside if statement in getBreedsSearch method");
        this.breedService.getBreedsSearch(this.breedName, this.speciesId).subscribe(result => {
            console.log("Inside the service method in if statement in getBreedsSearch method");
            this.breedsList = result.results;
        }, error => this.toastr.error(error.statusText, '', {
            timeOut: 3000
        }));
    } else {
        console.log("Inside else statement in getBreedsSearch method");
        this.getBreedsList();
        this.getSpeciesList();
    }
}
```

I used `(input)` to get the search data while input character, and I used `(change)` to get the selected item in combo box and get the search data directly.

> How can I get the search data when I do multiple search for both event
> and avoid error `"Cannot read property 'value' of undefined"` for
> speciesId when the combo box change the selected value?

I search a many resource and the below link is one of them: 
[angular 2 cannot read property of undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42336868/angular-2-cannot-read-property-of-undefined)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After long search, I find the solution,

> I used `[(ngModel)]` to pass `breedNameSearch` value, then I changed
> the `getBreedsSearch()` paramters to have only one parameter which is
> `speciesId` then I passed it using `$event`.

Solution:
**breeds.component.html**

```
<form class="form-inline" #searchForm>
<input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="search" placeholder="Enter Breed Name ..."
name="breedNameSearch" id="breedNameSearch" aria-label="Search"
(input)="getBreedsSearch()" [(ngModel)]="breedNameSearch">

<select class="select-option form-control" #speciesIdSearch name="speciesIdSearch"
(change)="getBreedsSearch($event.target.value)">
    <option [value]=0 hidden selected>-- select species name --</option>
    <option [value]=0>-- Select All --</option>
    <option *ngFor="let data of speciesList" [value]="data.speciesId">
        {{data.speciesName}}
    </option>
</select>
```

**breeds.service.ts**

```
getBreedsSearch(breedName: string, speciesId: number) {

    if(speciesId === undefined || speciesId === null)
    {
        speciesId = 0;
        console.log("Species Id = " + speciesId);
    }
    if(breedName === null || breedName === "")
    {
        breedName = "All";
    }
    let params = new HttpParams()
        .set("breedName", breedName)
        .set("speciesId", speciesId.toString());

    console.log(params);
    return this.http.get<Apiresponse>(this.baseUrl + 'BreedsMaster/GetBreedsSearch', { params: params })
}
```

**breeds.component.ts**

```
getBreedsSearch(speciesId:number) {
    if(speciesId === undefined || speciesId === null)
    {
        speciesId = 0;
        console.log("Species Id = " + speciesId);
    }
    
    console.log("breedName value = " + this.breedNameSearch);
    console.log("speciesId value = " + speciesId);
    if ((this.breedNameSearch != null || this.breedNameSearch != "") || (speciesId != null)) {
        console.log("If statement in getBreedsSearch method");
        this.breedService.getBreedsSearch(this.breedNameSearch, speciesId).subscribe(result => {
            console.log("Service method in if statement in getBreedsSearch method");
            this.breedsList = result.results;
        }, error => this.toastr.error(error.statusText, '', {
            timeOut: 3000
        }));
    } else {
        console.log("Else statement in getBreedsSearch method");
        this.getBreedsList();
        this.getSpeciesList();
    }
}
```

**It is work around, but I believe there are many ways to do this, hope this solution help.**

Answer (score 0):

When the user selects an item in the combo box, you call `getBreedsSearch('',$event)`.
Then in the first line of the function, you try to get `breedName.target.value` while the value of `breedName` is "".

You should check if `breedName` contains `target` property.
Try something like this:

```
getBreedsSearch(breedName, speciesId) {
    this.breedName = breedName.target && breedName.target.value;
    ...
```

Comment: I checked the `target` property, but it is not working though.